# In calculus, how should I interpret the -1 superscript in trigonometric functions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, notation, inverse-function

In calculus, and in the context of differentiating functions for practice, how should I interpret the following expression (i.e., what is the convention here)
$$f(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$$
Should I treat it as the inverse of tan or just $$\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$$

Comment: It's poor notation but $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is almost always the function $\arctan(x)$ while $\tan^n(x)$ for any other $n$ means raise tangent to that power.

Comment: @podiki Well, I would agree with *positive* $n$. No one sensible should use negative exponents there other than $-1$.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, I saw the graph of the function in question and it turned out to be the arctan as you suggested. You may post your answer and I shall accept :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I hope someone wouldn't use it without clarification, but if I saw $\tan^{-2}(x)$ with no context I'd assume it's the reciprocal square instead of either 1. The square of the inverse or 2. A composition of the inverse with itself.

Comment: Somewhat *off-topic* : Personally, because of the possibility of confusion, I usually avoid such syntax as $\tan^{-1}(x)$ and $\tan^{-2}(x)$.  For the first, I use $\text{arctan}(x)$.  For the second, I will either use $\left[\tan(x)\right]^{-2}$ or $\left[\text{arctan}(x)\right]^2$, depending on what is intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** This is a terrible collision of notation due to the fact that there are two kinds of binary operations on functions that are often denoted by *concatenation*, but the $-1$ exponent usually denotes the function composition inverse of the trig function that inputs a number and outputs an angle.

---

**Longish answer:** I have to clarify this every semester in my algebra/calculus classes, so here are some more complete thoughts.

Suppressing domain considerations, given functions $f$ and $g$, we can form the pointwise product whose value at $x$ is $f(x)\,g(x)$, or we can form the composition $\smash{f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)}$, either of which is often denoted by $fg$, depending on context. (Sometimes the composition is denoted $f \circ g$ to explicitly disambiguate the two, but read on.)

Each operation has an identity, say $e$. For multiplication, this is the constant function $x \mapsto 1$, so $fe = ef = f$ for any function $f$ since $f(x) \, 1 = 1 \, f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. However, for composition, this is the identity function $x \mapsto x$ so $fe = ef = f$ for any function $f$ since $f(e(x)) = e(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in this case.

Going further, we can combine a function with itself in either way. Should $f^2 = ff$ denote the product that evaluates to
$\smash{\bigl( f(x) \bigr)^2} = f(x) f(x)$?
Or should it denote the composition
$\smash{f\bigl( f(x) \bigr)}$?
Analogously, for any natural $n$, is
$f^n$ the $n$-fold pointwise product
$f(x) \cdots f(x)$ or the $n$-fold nested composition
$f(f(\cdots f(x) \cdots ))$?

And then there's the inverse, when it exists: The inverse of $f$ is the function $f^{-1}$ such that $ff^{-1} = f^{-1}f = e$, the identity. If you are working with *multiplication*, then
$f^{-1}(x) = \smash{\bigl( f(x) \bigr)^{-1}} = 1/f(x)$.
But if you are working with *composition*, the inverse is the function where $f^{-1}(x) = y$ means that $f(y) = x$.

This is a real problem with the trig functions, where we are genuinely interested in both kinds of inverse! To avoid this ambiguity, many of us avoid the superscript $\tan^{-1}$ notation entirely, instead opting for
$$
\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}
$$
for the multiplicative inverse, and
$$
\arctan x 
$$
for the compositional inverse, since either could reasonably be $\tan^{-1} x$.

---

**Addendum 1.** This problem becomes even more muddled in linear algebra, where two linear transformations, say $S$ and $T$, are represented in coordinates by matrices, say $A$ and $B$, and the composition $ST$ is represented by the *product* matrix $AB$, and that operation on the matrices is called multiplication (for good reasons, but I digress).

**(See [comment by David Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318763/in-calculus-how-should-i-interpret-the-1-superscript-in-trigonometric-function/4318848?noredirect=1#comment9001767_4318848) below.)** <strike>**Addendum 2.**</strike> <strike>In the object oriented paradigm in computer science, this multiple use of the same name that depends on context is celebrated under the name [*polymorphism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)), where objects of different classes can support a method of the same name.</strike>

---

The moral is that **context matters**, and notation only carries as much information as you imbue it with. Often, context is suppressed by relying on conventions, which is essentially what your question (and other spiritually similar questions about order-of-operations, etc.) *but we suppress that context at our peril!* We must aspire to communicate mathematics concisely, but unambiguously. Remember: **The notation works for you, not the other way around.**

Comment: I don't know if the comparison to polymorphism is particularly useful. I would say polymorphism in CS is more about different types of objects that can exhibit the same _behavior_, and in particular, about ways of guaranteeing that they exhibit the same behavior without depending on their intrinsic types. If some part of that behavior has to do with names, then sure, you might wind up with a situation where polymorphism involves using the same name to mean different things depending on context, but it's not fundamental to the concept of polymorphism.

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks. I am primarily a student of mathematics, mostly self-taught in computer languages. I appreciate your correction.

Answer (score 12):

$\tan^{-1}x=\arctan x$.  It is an unfortunate confluence of conventions, but fortunately the function $1/\tan x$ has a name, $\cot x$, making it easier to disambiguate.